# Fazer com que uma imagem cresça proporcionalmente ate limite especifico

Tags: css

Fazer com que uma imagem cresça proporcionalmente ao limite de uma area
segue o exemplo na imagem a baixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

### `max-width`

```
div.imagem{
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
}

div.imagem img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 198px; // Sua Primeira Imagem
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize somente a propriedade max-width, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
div.imagem img{
 max-width:100%;// primeira imagem
}
```

Você já definiu o tamanho da área onde a imagem será inserida, portanto a imagem ocupará 100% desta área.